# Как отобразить длительность воспроизводимой композиции из MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, время

При запуске плеера необходимо обновлять и выводить  время текущей композиции:
в данном коде обновляю seekbar ,как сделать так же и для времени композиции +реализация millisecondsToTime

```
 public void startMediaPlayer() {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
                mediaPlayer.start();


            }
        });

    }

private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (seekBar != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

        }
    };
```

Разметка:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayer"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:text="00:00"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: И что у вас не получается? Судя по коду вопрос из заголовка не актуален...

Comment: @xkor
обновил шапку и указал,что за код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот действительно так же и сделать)

```
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(millisecondsToTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
        }
```

Или вы как раз millisecondsToTime реализовать не можете? Тогда об этом бы и спрашивали. Этот метод будет выглядеть например так:

```
private String millisecondsToTime(int millis) {
    int min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
    int sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", min, sec);
}
```

Comment: @upward обновил ответ, а вам советую поработать над формулированием своих мыслей, я до конца ваше последнее сообщение так и не смог понять.

Comment: @ xkor
 textView.setText(millisecondsToTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
я прописываю данный код в методе старта плеера?

Comment: если хотите что бы он сработал только при старте плеера то да, но я думаю вы хотите обновлять время как и сикбар)